# Translating an awk command

Tags: awk

I am trying to understand the meaning of this line:

```
command = 'awk \'' + '$9 == "'+gene+'" && $4 >= ' + str(min_count) + '\' ' + filename + ' > ' + filename + '.tmp.' + gene
```

`gene, min_count, filename` are parameters of a function
Could somebody explain the purpose of this command?

Comment: Is this python code ?

Comment: @dash-o yeah it's inside a python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing the above python command will result the bash command:

```
awk '$9 == "$GENE" && $4 >= $MIN_COUNT' $FILENAME > $FILENAME.tmp.$GENE
```

Assuming that '$XYZ' represent the value of the python variable 'XYZ'

Which will do:

- Open file $filename for input
- Open file "$filename.tmp.$gene" for output
- For every input line

  - Check if the 9th argument equals $gene
  - Check if the 4th argument >= $min_count
  - If both condition are met, print the line to the output file.

As a side note, it will be more efficient, as less crypt to perform the following code in python.

```
filename="..."
gene="..."
min_count=...
inp = open(filename, 'r')
out = open(filename + '.tmp.' + gene, 'w') ;
for line in inp.readline():
    l = line.split(' ')
    if l[8] == gene and int(l[3]) >= min_count:
        out.write(line)
inp.close()
out.close()
```

Code not tested, as there is no data to verify, should be close enough